# React class component and using bind

Tags: reactjs

When using React class components, do we always need to use bind for event handlers (except for arrow functions) ?
Are there any exceptions/use cases when we do not have to explicitly bind as below;

```
constructor( props ){
    super( props );
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The rule of thumb:
We don't need to bind context inside constructor if function doesn't contain word `this`. If it does, than you probably need to bind context.

Comment: Thanks...but even if it has "this" word, but is an arrow function, we don't need to bind...correct ?